# Место менеджера памяти в проекте

Tags: c++, память

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот например есть некий проект (C++), достаточно серьёзный, чтобы необходимость использовать собственный менеджер памяти была очевидной. Тем не менее, мне не совсем ясно в какой именно момент я должен его реализовать и использовать. 
Например, я начал с чего-то не очень сложного, интуитивно понятного и нужного в рамках проекта - определение своих классов. При их определении и реализации я не использую никаких своих/сторонних менеджеров памяти кроме того, который предоставляется компилятором.
Вопрос состоит в том, надо ли сначала реализовать менеджер памяти, и уже с его использованием определять и реализовывать основные составляющие части программы, либо допускается использование управления памятью на более высоком уровне с готовыми комплексными структурами данных?

Собственно, с какой точки стоит подходить к ответу на этот вопрос? Может есть какие-то общие рекомендации, или какой стандарт?

Comment: Серьёзность проекта не обязательно подразумевает необходимость создания своего менеджера. Если вы на этапе проектирования решили, что вам он нужен, логично было бы сразу его и использовать(для этого удобно может быть просто определить его интерфейс, который поначалу может быть просто оберткой над дефолтным, а написать вы его потом можете в любой момент). Собственно подобное относится вообще в любым классам, функциям и тп. Суть вашего вопроса мне вообще не совсем понятна, что такое по-вашему управление на более высоком уровне?

Comment: Если на проекте работаете только вы, то лучше использовать готовый менеджер памяти(стандартный). Проблем от своего велосипеда обычно бывает больше, чем от съедания памяти.